# I am beginning to setup MongoDB. I don't know how to find my Host address or port number after downloading the file for windows?? Can anyone help me?

Tags: mongodb, port, host

I am beginning to setup Mongo DB. I don't know how to find my Host address or port number after downloading the file for windows?? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you have setup your MongoDB on your local machine the host address is *localhost*. After starting the `mongod` process the following ports are the default ones:

- 27017 - The default port for the mongod or mongos instance
- 27018 - The default port when running with **--shardsvr** runtime operation
- 27019 - The default port when running with **--configsvr** runtime operation
- 28017 - The default port for the web status page

You can also read about this more in the [official documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/).

Remember that you can override the default ports with parameters passed to `mongod` during the startup.

Comment: Do you happen to know if MongoDB is capable of working with Go Daddy. My goal is to have a website using API to have live data from a mongodb site. The only thing I see on the godaddy dashboard for databases is MYSQL. Is it possible to use MYSQL to obtain api information from a sports website that has given me an API key?? Thanks for your help Horizon

Comment: I'm not familiar with GoDaddy, but according to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/gp5jzYbdTMQ) you can setup a virtual server (for example running CentOS) and install your MongoDB there.